# Symfony 2 hidden form field text

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

This is probably really stupid but I am trying to set a hidden form field value in symfony yet when I do a view source, the value doesnt show up.  this->postID refers to a value I am passing in through the constructor, but that doesnt matter, even if I set the data value to a string it doesn't show.  I must be doing something really stupid.. Here is my form..

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('text','text');
        $builder->add('IsshPost','hidden', array('data'=>$this->postID));
    }
```

any idea whats wrong?

Comment: Anybody? I'd really appreciate some help! been stuck on this

Comment: Could you please paste the complete code?

Comment: I figured it out.. thanks! basically you have to detach the field from the entity by passing an extra field "property_path => false"

Answer (score 7):

I figured it out.. thanks! basically you have to detach the field from the entity by passing an extra field

```
"property_path => false"
```

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony 2.1, the "data" option is fixed in that regard. The code in question should work out of the box there.